# Why is this SQL injection 'sleep' attack an effective denial of service?

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

Today, while administering a client's server, our monitoring identified some slow page load times / other issues.  I noticed while troubleshooting this, that the following query was in the process list and never seemed to finish:

```
SELECT *
FROM   motorcycles
       LEFT JOIN motorcycle_year
              ON motorcycle_year.year_id = motorcycles.motorcycle_vyear
       LEFT JOIN motorcycle_make
              ON motorcycle_make.make_id = motorcycles.motorcycle_vmake
       LEFT JOIN dealers
              ON dealers.dealer_id = motorcycles.motorcycle_dealer
       LEFT JOIN motorcycle_subtype
              ON subtype_id = motorcycle_subtype
       LEFT JOIN fuel_type
              ON fuel_id = motorcycle_fuel
WHERE  motorcycle_id = -3885
        OR 1073 = Sleep(5)
           AND motorcycle_dealer = '91'
```

At first I thought it was a bug in the client's code, but then I determined it must be the result of SQL injection because of this part:

```
WHERE  motorcycle_id = -3885
        OR 1073 = Sleep(5)
           AND motorcycle_dealer = '91'
```

So it seems like some sort of sql injection DOS attack.  For technical reasons that I don't understand, this query never seems to complete.

I tried to reproduce it in a simpler context with a test table and a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  id = -9000
        OR 1073 = Sleep(5)
           AND foo = 'bar'
```

But as I expected, it finished in roughly 5 seconds.  So why does the former query never complete?  Does it have to do with the joins?  I'd like to understand this out of pure curiosity at this point.

If this is better suited for another stack exchange forum, feel free to migrate the question there.

Edit:  And just to be clear, the former query (the one that seems to be a DOS sql injection) returns almost instantly if I replace with similar, but saner values like:

```
WHERE motorcycle_id =
1 AND motorcycle_dealer = '91';
```

Comment: How many records were in your test table?

Comment: @PM77-1 only 1.  Wait...  Is it doing a SLEEP(5) for every record?

Comment: that'd seem right. it evaluates the predicate for each record

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe I didn't put that together in my head until you asked me that @PM77-1 .  Thanks.  Feel free to submit an answer and I'll mark it as solved if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on the ettiquette here but I just wanted to mark this as solved with the help of PM77-1's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679283/why-is-this-sql-injection-sleep-attack-an-effective-denial-of-service#comment49419735_30679283)

Basically the `SLEEP(5)` happens for every record since the conditional must be evaluated for each.  In my test table, I only had one record, so I could not reproduce the seemingly never-ending query.

Answer (score 0):

I think of SQL injection attacks as malicious.  Poorly written SQL queries would be different.  Many joins involve more tables and more operations.  The reproduction of the complex where clause may have been fast.  If the other tables were going through queries, backups, re-indexing, they may have been performing slowly.  The where clause has ambiguous columns in the multi-table query with joins.  You may want to use table aliases to eliminate the ambiguity.

All things constant, the where clause that uses a number equivalence test should have performed more quickly than the regex (string equivalence test).  But the real world is more complex than we can theorize.  Given the complexity of the joins, the sleep(5) may be invoked more times in the where clause.  That would explain why the reproduction miniquery to isolate the problem finishes in such a short amount of time.

Comment: I'm curious why my answer was downvoted. Can someone give me more information?

Comment: It wasn't a bad answer, I think it's just that @PM77-1 hit the nail on the head.  I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted though.